# Why does my counter project increase the value before decreasing and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, html, function, counter

I have made a project that is a simple counter with three buttons “decrease”, “reset” and “increase”

Each have onclick events attached to them.

Here is my code for my html file and each function respectively in my js file.

```
<body>
  <wrapper>
    <h1>Counter</h1>
    <h2 id="counter">0</h2>
     <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
        <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        <button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
     </div>
 </wrapper>
</body>
```

```
Let i = 0;

function increase() {
  document.getElementById(‘counter’).innerHTML = i;
i++;
}

function decrease() {
  document.getElementById(‘counter’).innerHTML = i;
i—-;
}

function reset() {

i = 0;
document.getElementById(‘counter’).innerHTML = i
}
```

I’ve been trying to figure why when I make my code in this order for increase() and decrease() functions it seems to for example....if counter is at 1 and I click increase, I have to click it twice before it increases but then when I click decrease, it will increase it by 1 and then decrease and vice versa as well?

But when I have the i++ or i-- first before getting the id it seems to work fine? e.g.

```
Let i = 0;

function increase() {
i++;
  document.getElementById(‘counter’).innerHTML = i;

}

function decrease() {
i--;
  document.getElementById(‘counter’).innerHTML = i;
}
```

I’m not sure why it does this if anyone can help?

I’ve solved this in terms of getting the project to work the way I want but I can’t work out why the increase would decrease the counter before increasing and vice versa when my functions don’t reference each other in any way?

Comment: Can you also include the code where you call those functions?

Comment: `document.getElementById(‘counter’) = i;` makes no sense to begin with - you can not just "overwrite" an HTML _element_, with an _integer_. (Have you not bothered to check the browser console? This should have given you an error saying something like "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment".) This should be something like `document.getElementById(‘counter’).innerHTML = i;`. And of course you need to do it _after_ you actually manipulated `i`, and not before ...

Comment: Well you need to put the i-- / i++ before dom manipulation, and also change the value of your input aka :  `document.getElementById(‘counter’).value = i` assuming your element is an input, if it's not then simply use innerText instead

Comment: _"But when I have the i++ or i-- first before getting the id it seems to work fine?"_ - if you were to send a fax, then it would also matter whether you wrote on the paper that you let the sending fax machine scan, _before_ or _after_ you send the fax. So why should this be any different? You are not creating any "permanent connection" between the variable and the HTML element here - you are writing the _current_ value of the variable, into the element. That element content is _static_, until you change it again. The element content, that is, not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Code is executed from the top to the bottom, not the other way around

```js
let i = 0;

function increase() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
}

function decrease() {
  i--;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i;
}

function reset() {
  i = 0;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = i
}
```

```html
<button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<button onclick="increase()">Increase</button>
<p id="counter">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are "**Value Types**", which means if you assign them to a new variable or pass them into a function, the value will be copied. In contrast, on "**Reference Types**", the behaviour is just the pointer will be copied instead of the value.

Value Type sample:

```js
let i = 4;
let j = i;
i++; // it only changes i
```

Reference Type sample:

```js
let i = {value:4};
let j = i;
i.value++; // it also changes j
```